# How should I edit a model entry in mvc?

Tags: html, model-view-controller, edit, models

I am working on a small app using phalcon for php framework. I have implemented multiple controllers and models, but so far when I want to edit a user for example, i use a link that links to

> localhost/myappname/User/edit/11 "user's id"

I was told this is not the best way to do this, and I am trying to do this without passing the id through the url, like using post method like in forms but without success so far.
Is this the only correct way to edit or delete an entry or it there something better?
I tried to search for the problem but couldn't figure how to name this question so I am yet to find an answered question.

Comment: I think you are doing that in a good way, you don't need to POST user id. But if you want you can create a custom route for that. Why it is not a good way to do this like you did?

Comment: @MilosMiskoneSretin I don't know I am still a beginner and I'm currently an intern. I think because anyone can type what he wants to access in the url, which is not fine with my employer. I think he wants that when i want to edit the entry, i use the edit action without a parameter and get the id using post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you don't want to let everyone access to edit page you can do this in a few ways.

## **Solution #1**

You can use Phalcon ACL to block user's who has no permission to edit this page so only allowed people like managers can edit user or whatever.

[See Access Control Lists ACL](https://docs.phalconphp.com/en/latest/reference/acl.html)

## **Solution #2**

You can crypt/decrypt user id so in URL it will not be readable by humans and then in edit method try to dectypt that id and if it is not a valid echo error.

```
<?php

    use Phalcon\Crypt;

    // Create an instance
    $crypt   = new Crypt();

    $key     = 'le password';
    $user_id = 5;

    $encrypt = $crypt->encryptBase64($user_id, $key);
    // Use $encrypt for URL like <a href="/User/edit/{{encrypt}}">Edit</a>

    // Use decrypt to get the real id of a user
    $crypt->decryptBase64($encrypt, $key);

?>
```

In this way users will see URL something like

> localhost/myappname/User/edit/nomGPPXd+gAEazAP8ERF2umTrfl9GhDw1lxVvf39sGKF34AFNzok31VdaT/OwADPPJ4XgaUNClQKrlc/2MfaXQ==

For more info see [Encryption/Decryption](https://docs.phalconphp.com/en/latest/reference/crypt.html)

But my personal opinion is that it is better to go with ACL. After all ACL was made for that kind of things.

> **Note!** If you want to use Encrypt/Decript remember to wrap decryption
>   in edit method in `try/catch` block and catch exception so you don't
>   get Error if someone tries to guess sone id.

## **Solution #3**

If you still want to do that using POST then don't use `<a href="...">Edit</a>` instead you can try something like:

```
<form method="POST">
    <input type="hidden" name="uid" value="{{ user_id }}"/>
    <button type="submit">Edit</button>
</form>
```

And then in edit method catch that id like:

```
<?php
    $user_id = $this->request->getPost("uid");
?>
```

> **NOTE!** In this way your URL will not contain user id but someone still
>   can POST another uid so you can try to hide that real user id even
>   from *input type hidden*. You can use again crypt/decrypt so *input
>   hidden uid* can be crypted and then decrypt post data in method.

Comment: I was able to solve the problem using your third solution, thanks. I want to ask you what in your opinion is the best solution? Please not that I already have an acl implemented, but when a user wants to delete a blog post for example, I want him to be able to delete his own posts but not that of others. Can this be done using the acl? Or is the acl only able to allow him to either access delete or not?

Comment: That is out of scope of this question. Please ask another question so we can answer and let other people who is seeking for that answer to find it. StackOverflow is not a chat so you need to open another question for that.

Comment: 3rd solution combined with crypt works great for me. Nice idea.

Answer (score 0):

you could use sessionStorage. It would store the value of the userId in the browser and be deleted as soon as they leave the page.

http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_webstorage.asp

set on one page

```
sessionStorage.userId = 11;
```

access on another

```
var user = sessionStoarge.userId;
```

Comment: How can I do this when I have multiple entries for user on the same page? This is a view where I can edit any user not just me. I am using php btw so I am able to store data in a session, but when should I store the id?

Comment: Can you give me a little more context for what your trying to do?

Comment: I am learning the framework on a small app. I have a controller and a model for users, and there is an admin user who is allowed to access everything. I have implemented a dynamic acl where each user has resources he is eligible to access, and these resources can be changed from the edit user view. The cause of the problem is that I want a user to be able to delete his own posts in the blog for example but not someone else's, so this makes the acl not suitable because if he has the permission to delete, he can just type any url and guess the id even if I hide the delete button.

Comment: when the user logs in, save the userId in the sessionStorage. Then when they load the edit user page, check if the id for the user matches the sessionStorage variable. If they do not match, redirect them